# Matrix Multiplication Composition from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I've came with a very simple question, which asks to show that $A^3 = 0$, given that:

$$A(x,y,z)  = (ay+bz, cz, 0)$$

However, I don't comprehend how to multiply this $A$ times itself. I tried to multiply as a row vector times a column vector but it didn't get the same result.

Comment: $A$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence $A^3$ means $A \circ A \circ A$ (composition, not multiplication).

Comment: Yes, I know this fact.

Comment: Well, just compute $A^3(x,y,z)$ for any vector $(x,y,z)$, then.

Comment: your $A$ as a matrix is $$\left[\begin{matrix}0 & a& b\\ 0&0&c\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: @razivo *in the canonical basis...

Comment: @dynamicalsystems Do those comments help you at all? If not, please state what's unclear. For example, did you manage to see the map $A$ as a multiplication "on the left" with the matrix given by @razivo?

Comment: I would like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be the matrix representation of the linear operator $A$.
$$B\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ay+bz\\cz\\0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&a&b\\ 0&0&c \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$B^3=O$$
$$A^3=0$$

alternatively,
$$A^2(x,y,z)=(acz,0,0)$$
$$A^3(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$$